# Forwarding calls from Apache server to cpp server both running on Raspberry

Tags: linux, apache-httpd

I am using raspberry Pi B+ and i have installed both , Apache server and my own cpp server , running on different ports.The cpp server is based on 'GNU Libmicrohttpd' library and i can choose a specific port for it.The Apache server is by default running on port 80. I would like to put the Apache server in front and forward calls for my cpp server.I read that load balancing is supported by Raspberry, i have to install a lightweight proxy server like NGINX or Varnish in order to do this. My question is : Is there anyone who tried this , does it actually work on the raspberry? other suggestions ?